# HDMI not detected anymore

Tags: hdmi, monitor, mate

I had a normally working Lenovo S27i-10 monitor on the HMDI port of my Ubuntu Mate 20.04 system.
It is suddenly not detected anymore:

```
henk@henk-N24-25BU ~> xrandr | grep 'connected'                                                  
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Monitor works normally on VGA. The monitor shows as disconnected on a different laptop running Xubuntu as well.
Monitor works perfectly well on Windows laptop using the same HDMI cable.

How can I connect this monitor on the HMDI port again on Ubuntu?
(in other words, how can I diagnose where the problem is and solve it).

Comment: If 2 different machines tell you they can not connect then its the monitor and or the cable that is bad.

Comment: @David I have tried different HDMI cables. I don't understand why the monitor worked in the morning with a cable with which it didn't work anymore in the afternoon.

Comment: @Community - I would like to get help with diagnosing this problem. What do you need to know what is happening here. End goal was stated in the question - how can I get the HDMI status to "connected" again.

Comment: Things break. Something has happened to the HDMI connection in the monitor it seems.

Comment: OK, the monitor is actually brand new. How do I know it is the monitor?

Comment: @David - I have checked the monitor on a Windows laptop using the same HDMI cable and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hove you been able to test the HDMI  on the computer where it no longer works with another monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

This produced:

```
gdm.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "reload" failed.
```

after which everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I've got Lenovo P50s laptop with Kubuntu 20.04 and it too stopped detecting my HDMI monitor recently.

The solution as suggested by @BeastOfCaerbannog didn't work for me.

After today's slew of package updates though, it started working again, so perhaps it looks like a software defect, that was subsequently fixed again.

Comment: Now on Kubuntu 21.04, HDMI monitor worked until today's updates. Now it is no longer detected - again.